# Image gallery with overlapping 

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Image Gallery with overlapping Fade In and Fade Out effects ???

I'm trying to find an idea to go by or some code snippet for an Xml Img. gallery where I can use Images which are fading 'In and Out' before showing the next Img. a type of overlapping, and which than again does the fade In and Out thing.

**** I have been able to get things going through the last week, but I'm not too happy with it as it is not smooth enough!, and not that greatly dissolving between Imgs.

Here is a Link of a gallery which has that what I'm looking for !!!
[link text](http://www.rbphotography.co.uk/gallery.swf)

Thanks a lot in advance. regards aktell

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this yet.

can you try creating two overlapping canvases.

first image in the first canvas which fades from alpha 1 to 0 and second image fades from 0 to 1. Then second image replaces first one in 1st canvas giving way to third image in second canvas.

Comment: Thanks  a lot but I have tried that already, and it did not work the way I want it to be! regards aktell